# Stack of Plates: Cracking the coding interview

Tags: stack

Stack of Plates: Imagine a (literal) stack of plates. If the stack gets too high, it might topple.
Therefore, in real life, we would likely start a new stack when the previous stack exceeds some threshold. Implement a data structure SetOfStacks that mimics this. SetOfStacks should be composed of several stacks and should create a new stack once the previous one exceeds capacity.

SetOfStacks. push () and SetOfStacks. pop() should behave identically to a single stack (that is, pop ( ) should return the same values as it would if there were just a single stack).
FOLLOW UP
Implement a function **popAt (int index)** which performs a pop operation on a specific substack.
The book solution for pop at index:

```
   public int popAt(int index) {
21 return leftShift (index, true);
22 }
23
24 public int leftShift(int index, boolean removeTop) {
25 Stack stack = stacks.get(index);
26 int removed_item;
27 if (removeTop) removed_item = stack.pop();
28 else removed_item = stack.removeBottom( );
29 if (stack.isEmpty(» {
30 stacks.remove(index);
31 } else if (stacks.size() > index + 1) {
32 int v = leftShift(index + 1, false);
33 stack . push(v);
34 }
35 return removed_item;
36 }
```

the explanation of line **32 i nt v = leftShift(index + 1, false);** is missing. Can anyone please help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the **leftShift** function's objective is to pop from the stack given in the "index" input. After this, it does the adjustment between the other stacks.
So, in line 27 pops the element from the specified stack.

After this, in line 32, it calls itself recursively, giving this time as a first argument the index of the next stack, and as a second false. The first argument indicates that in the next recursive call, it will use the next stack. The second argument, being set as false, means that the required action (pop) has been done, and now only the adjustment is left.

The function when the flag **removeTop** is set as false does the adjustment as I referred above. The difference, in this case, is that instead of the top element it removes the bottom one from each of the following stacks. This way the needed adjustment is done.
With the term adjustment, I mean the elements that need to be moved from the next stacks to the previous ones each time so as to fill any empty spaces.

I hope it helps.